# Is there a way to add extension on startup firefox with selenium on nodejs?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

I have tried some examples from documentation, but, no success...

A example that add extension to firefox and work`s almost like a charm:

```js
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
let firefoxOptions = new firefox.Options();
let firefoxProfile = new firefox.Profile("bals9uot.default-release");
firefoxProfile.addExtension("/home/reni/Área de Trabalho/dev/auto_anvisa/bals9uot.default-release/extensions/{e58d3966-3d76-4cd9-8552-1582fbc800c1}.xpi");
firefoxOptions.setProfile(firefoxProfile);
```

This failed after load extension to browser, because I need re-enable extension on settings in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest version I could get this to work.

However, I think `firefox.Profile` has been removed as now it will by default run with an anonymous profile (see https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/firefox)

E.g. in my example below I take a screenshot which shows the dark reader extension working.

```
const {Builder} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const fs = require('fs');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');

(async function example() {
  let options = new firefox.Options().addExtensions('dark_reader-4.9.32-an+fx.xpi');

  let driver = await new Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .setFirefoxOptions(options)
    .build();

  try {
    await driver.get('https://google.com/');

    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
    const image = await driver.takeScreenshot();
    fs.writeFileSync('out.png', image, { encoding: 'base64' })

  } finally {
    await driver.quit();
  }
})();
```